# Deploying Django application To AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: django, linux, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a django application to AWS ElasticBeanstalk. I am working on a Linux machine. It all goes well but when deployment is done I get "502 Gateway Error". From a deep search I found that people with the similar problem created Procfile to the root directory of the project and added the following to that: "web: gunicorn--bind :8000 --workers 3 --threads 2 applicationName.wsgi:application". I tried that but then I get "ServiceError - Failed to deploy application." Any clues on that?

Comment: Have you fixed the issue? If not the first thing you should do is check the logs.

Comment: I was able to solve that, check the answer. But there wasn't any useful info related to that.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty weird but it was showing that Gateway Error only because I had left

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']
```

After changing that to

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['app_url'] 
# where app_url is the url provided by eb when it is deployed firstly
```